# Soundcard for Ableton Live with low latency

Tags: music, sound-cards, midi

I use Ableton Live 10 with a fast computer and it was working well until I connected several MIDI drum machines (Roland 808, Roland 909). Then it started lagging because my ASIO driver does not have a good enough soundcard, presumably.

What should I buy? I presume it is my sound card that I need to upgrade. I have tried all the settings and the latency still appears when I connect the external instruments.

My budget is good, I can spend at least 1000 USD.